# Poetry - RuntimeError: No python executable found in shell environment. Tried: ['python3', 'python', 'py.exe -3', 'py.exe -2']

Tags: python-3.x, curl, anaconda, git-bash, python-poetry

Goal: Get **Poetry** working via **Git Bash**.

- Windows 10
- Poetry **1.1.13**
- [pyproject.toml](https://gist.github.com/danielbellhv/9934acc860f38093474d67afff7be736)

### Issue

Git Bash:

```
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~/Anaconda3
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python
Retrieving Poetry metadata

This installer is deprecated. Poetry versions installed using this script will not be able to use 'self update' command to upgrade to 1.2.0a1 or later.
# Welcome to Poetry!

This will download and install the latest version of Poetry,
a dependency and package manager for Python.

It will add the `poetry` command to Poetry's bin directory, located at:

%USERPROFILE%\.poetry\bin

This path will then be added to your `PATH` environment variable by
modifying the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Environment/PATH` registry key.

You can uninstall at any time by executing this script with the --uninstall option,
and these changes will be reverted.

Installing version: 1.1.13
  - Downloading poetry-1.1.13-win32.tar.gz (71.14MB)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1118, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1114, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 362, in run
  File "<stdin>", line 556, in install
  File "<stdin>", line 704, in make_bin
  File "<stdin>", line 693, in _which_python
RuntimeError: No python executable found in shell environment. Tried: ['python3', 'python', 'py.exe -3', 'py.exe -2']
```

So, I went into `Anaconda3`, duplicated `python.exe`, renaming it `python3.exe`:

```
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~/Anaconda3
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python3
bash: python3: command not found
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
(base)
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~/Anaconda3
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python3
Retrieving Poetry metadata

This installer is deprecated. Poetry versions installed using this script will not be able to use 'self update' command to upgrade to 1.2.0a1 or later.
Latest version already installed.
(base)
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~
```

```
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/lumada-catalog/synthetic-data-gen (daniel_sims)
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python3
Retrieving Poetry metadata

This installer is deprecated. Poetry versions installed using this script will not be able to use 'self update' command to upgrade to 1.2.0a1 or later.
Latest version already installed.
(base)
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/lumada-catalog/synthetic-data-gen (daniel_sims)
$ poetry install
bash: poetry: command not found
(base)
```

---

I then tried Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\dabell> (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://install.python-poetry.org -UseBasicParsing).Content | python3       Retrieving Poetry metadata

# Welcome to Poetry!

This will download and install the latest version of Poetry,
a dependency and package manager for Python.

It will add the `poetry` command to Poetry's bin directory, located at:

C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts

You can uninstall at any time by executing this script with the --uninstall option,
and these changes will be reverted.

Installing Poetry (1.1.13)
Installing Poetry (1.1.13): Creating environment
Installing Poetry (1.1.13): Installing Poetry
Installing Poetry (1.1.13): Creating script
Installing Poetry (1.1.13): Done

Poetry (1.1.13) is installed now. Great!

To get started you need Poetry's bin directory (C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts) in your `PATH`
environment variable.

Alternatively, you can call Poetry explicitly with `C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\poetry`.

You can test that everything is set up by executing:

`poetry --version`

PS C:\Users\dabell> poetry --version
poetry : The term 'poetry' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ poetry --version
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (poetry:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

```
PS C:\Users\dabell> echo ($env:path)
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.56.1\bin;
C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3;
C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3\Scripts;
C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310;
C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;
C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts;
```

The last line I've successfully added.

---

Git Bash:

```
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/lumada-catalog/synthetic-data-gen (daniel_sims)
$ poetry --version
Poetry version 1.1.13
(base)

HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/lumada-catalog/synthetic-data-gen (daniel_sims)
$ poetry install

  EnvCommandError

  Command C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3\python.exe -W ignore - errored with the following return code 1, and output:
  input was : import sys

  if hasattr(sys, "real_prefix"):
      print(sys.real_prefix)
  elif hasattr(sys, "base_prefix"):
      print(sys.base_prefix)
  else:
      print(sys.prefix)


  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py:1195 in _run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1180, in _run
    output = subprocess.run(
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\_compat.py", line 217, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(
poetry.utils._compat.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3\python.exe -W ignore -' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\console_application.py", line 131, in run
    status_code = command.handle(parsed_args, io)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\command\command.py", line 120, in handle
    status_code = self._do_handle(args, io)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\command\command.py", line 163, in _do_handle
    self._dispatcher.dispatch(PRE_HANDLE, event)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\event\event_dispatcher.py", line 22, in dispatch
    self._do_dispatch(listeners, event_name, event)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\event\event_dispatcher.py", line 89, in _do_dispatch
    listener(event, event_name, self)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\console\config\application_config.py", line 119, in set_env
    env = env_manager.create_venv(io)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 659, in create_venv
    env = self.get(reload=True)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 520, in get
    return self.get_system_env()
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 886, in get_system_env
    env = GenericEnv(base_prefix, child_env=env)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1498, in __init__
    super(GenericEnv, self).__init__(path, base=base)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1375, in __init__
    self._base = Path(self.run_python_script(GET_BASE_PREFIX).strip())
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1163, in run_python_script
    return self.run(self._executable, "-W", "ignore", "-", input_=content, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1152, in run
    return self._run(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1566, in _run
    return super(VirtualEnv, self)._run(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1195, in _run
    raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
poetry.utils.env.EnvCommandError: Command C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3\python.exe -W ignore - errored with the following return code 1, and output:
input was : import sys

if hasattr(sys, "real_prefix"):
    print(sys.real_prefix)
elif hasattr(sys, "base_prefix"):
    print(sys.base_prefix)
else:
    print(sys.prefix)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\poetry.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\console\__init__.py", line 5, in main
    return Application().run()
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\console_application.py", line 142, in run
    trace.render(io, simple=isinstance(e, CliKitException))
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\ui\components\exception_trace.py", line 232, in render
    return self._render_exception(io, self._exception)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\ui\components\exception_trace.py", line 269, in _render_exception
    self._render_snippet(io, current_frame)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\ui\components\exception_trace.py", line 289, in _render_snippet
    self._render_line(io, code_line)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\ui\components\exception_trace.py", line 402, in _render_line
    io.write_line("{}{}".format(indent * " ", line))
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\cleo\io\io_mixin.py", line 65, in write_line
    super(IOMixin, self).write_line(string, flags)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\io\io.py", line 66, in write_line
    self._output.write_line(string, flags=flags)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\io\output.py", line 69, in write_line
    self.write(string, flags=flags, new_line=True)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\io\output.py", line 61, in write
    self._stream.write(to_str(formatted))
  File "C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\clikit\io\output_stream\stream_output_stream.py", line 24, in write
    self._stream.write(string)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 28: character maps to <undefined>
(base)
```

Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\dabell\Documents\GitHub\lumada-catalog\synthetic-data-gen> poetry install

  EnvCommandError

  Command C:\Users\dabell\Anaconda3\python.exe -W ignore - errored with the following return code 1, and output:
  input was : import sys

  if hasattr(sys, "real_prefix"):
      print(sys.real_prefix)
  elif hasattr(sys, "base_prefix"):
      print(sys.base_prefix)
  else:
      print(sys.prefix)


  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py:1195 in _run
      1191│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1192│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
      1193│                 )
      1194│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1195│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1196│
      1197│         return decode(output)
      1198│
      1199│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):
```

---

Uninstalled everything conda and Poetry related.

Miniconda3:

```
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/lumada-catalog/synthetic-data-gen (daniel_sims)
$ poetry install

  EnvCommandError

  Command C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\python.exe -W ignore - errored with the following return code 1, and output:
  input was : import sys

  if hasattr(sys, "real_prefix"):
      print(sys.real_prefix)
  elif hasattr(sys, "base_prefix"):
      print(sys.base_prefix)
  else:
      print(sys.prefix)


  at ~\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py:1195 in _run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1180, in _run
    output = subprocess.run(
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\_compat.py", line 217, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(
poetry.utils._compat.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\python.exe -W ignore -' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\console_application.py", line 131, in run
    status_code = command.handle(parsed_args, io)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\command\command.py", line 120, in handle
    status_code = self._do_handle(args, io)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\command\command.py", line 163, in _do_handle
    self._dispatcher.dispatch(PRE_HANDLE, event)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\event\event_dispatcher.py", line 22, in dispatch
    self._do_dispatch(listeners, event_name, event)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\event\event_dispatcher.py", line 89, in _do_dispatch
    listener(event, event_name, self)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\poetry\console\config\application_config.py", line 119, in set_env
    env = env_manager.create_venv(io)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 659, in create_venv
    env = self.get(reload=True)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 531, in get
    return VirtualEnv(prefix, base_prefix)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1375, in __init__
    self._base = Path(self.run_python_script(GET_BASE_PREFIX).strip())
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1163, in run_python_script
    return self.run(self._executable, "-W", "ignore", "-", input_=content, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1152, in run
    return self._run(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1453, in _run
    return super(VirtualEnv, self)._run(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py", line 1195, in _run
    raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
poetry.utils.env.EnvCommandError: Command C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\python.exe -W ignore - errored with the following return code 1, and output:
input was : import sys

if hasattr(sys, "real_prefix"):
    print(sys.real_prefix)
elif hasattr(sys, "base_prefix"):
    print(sys.base_prefix)
else:
    print(sys.prefix)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\Scripts\poetry-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\poetry\console\__init__.py", line 5, in main
    return Application().run()
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\console_application.py", line 142, in run
    trace.render(io, simple=isinstance(e, CliKitException))
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\ui\components\exception_trace.py", line 232, in render
    return self._render_exception(io, self._exception)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\ui\components\exception_trace.py", line 269, in _render_exception
    self._render_snippet(io, current_frame)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\ui\components\exception_trace.py", line 289, in _render_snippet
    self._render_line(io, code_line)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\ui\components\exception_trace.py", line 402, in _render_line
    io.write_line("{}{}".format(indent * " ", line))
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\cleo\io\io_mixin.py", line 65, in write_line
    super(IOMixin, self).write_line(string, flags)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\io\io.py", line 66, in write_line
    self._output.write_line(string, flags=flags)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\io\output.py", line 69, in write_line
    self.write(string, flags=flags, new_line=True)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\api\io\output.py", line 61, in write
    self._stream.write(to_str(formatted))
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\site-packages\clikit\io\output_stream\stream_output_stream.py", line 24, in write
    self._stream.write(string)
  File "C:\Users\dabell\Miniconda3\envs\sdg\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 28: character maps to <undefined>
(sdg)
HDS+dabell@PF2DCSXD MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/lumada-catalog/synthetic-data-gen (daniel_sims)
$
```

Comment: [Git Issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5930)

Comment: Make sure that you have your python / poetry installation directories on your path. Seems like your shell is not finding the executables, which typically means a path issue.  What do you get if you write `echo ($env:path)` in your powershell?  Do you see the path `C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts` in the list? If not, do add it to the environment variables on your system and try again. (You probably have the same problem with Anaconda as it doesn't seem to find your Python)

Comment: Following [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0). Under `user variables`, add `C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts` to `path`. See `echo ($env: path)`.

Comment: Seems you've got that path set up which is nice. There might now be an issue with your python if you manually renamed python.exes etc., so if the issues persist I would recommend a full conda removal and re-install (same with poetry) and try again if that's an option.  Seems there might be some more fundamental issues going wrong here than just the path. Might be that your python3.exe that you mentioned you manually handled got corrupted in the copy process and cannot run due to that. Does `poetry --version` work on any shell at all?

Comment: Git Bash: `$ poetry --version Poetry version 1.1.13`

Comment: Seems like your poetry is set up to work correctly but your base environment's python still has some hiccups. I would try a fresh anaconda install myself at this point, making sure to remove any earlier conda traces from your system first with [anaconda-clean](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) following the steps in **2. Option B.** in the link (I've done this a fair few times myself having broken everything first). I'm also not quite sure why your powershell can't find poetry if Git Bash can.

Comment: Does the `poetry install` fail on powershell as well? If so, the issue is quite probably now with your conda/python rather than poetry.

Comment: `poetry` is **not** in `C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts`.

Comment: OK - I'm officially stuck. Made this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72829246/16852041)

Comment: I hope you've solved this by now but I just ran into a Git Bash issue with conda myself with character encodings and was able to solve it like [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7445) by setting the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable to "UTF-8" - hope this might still be of some value.

Comment: I never sis solve anything Poetry related. Apparently, I'm using an outdated installer, yet I've perfectly followed all the steps on their docs.

Comment: Thanks @Huug. I'll give it a look in the future when I've time.